# How to extract a .gz file in hadoop cluster environment?

Tags: hadoop

How to extract a .gz file in hadoop cluster environment , via java code without copying file to local(extracting directly in hadoop through code)?

Comment: Is this as input to a MapReduce job?

Comment: @BinaryNerd No.

Answer (score 0):

"**gunzip -k file.gz**" is usually used to unpack the .gz file keeping the original .gz as well, is it what you were looking for?

Comment: no.... I want code in java to extract....need to do this via code....not via terminal...

Answer (score 0):

Consider your .gz file has one file in it, you can do like this:

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
Path inFile = new Path(argv[0]);
Path outFile = new Path(argv[1]);

FSDataInputStream in = fs.open(inFile);
org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec.GzipInputStream gis = new org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec.GzipInputStream(in);
FSDataOutputStream out = fs.create(outFile);

doCopy(gis, out);

public static void doCopy(FSDataInputStream is, FSDataOutputStream os) throws Exception {
    int oneByte;
    while ((oneByte = is.read()) != -1) {
        os.write(oneByte);
    }
    os.close();
    is.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the other way of doing this you can create a shell script and run the same script whenever you need. or els you try implement terminal commands in your code.

If you want to do it from terminal you can run this command

gzip [ -acdfhlLnNrtvV19 ] [-S suffix] [ name ... ]
gunzip [ -acfhlLnNrtvV ] [-S suffix] [ name ... ]

source : https://www.techonthenet.com/linux/commands/gzip.php